# the last element in ul goes to next row

Tags: html, css

in my ul list the last element goes to next line. I want all li elements on one row. And secondly when I make my browser smaller then when login link gets close to ul, it (login link) also goes to next line. I want them to be in one row.

Here is my code [jsfddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QupAV/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You float *everything,* which may confuse the system.

How about you remove the float from the ul, so it will take up all the available width. And to keep the login link to the right of the ul, you can place the login link above the ul.

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QupAV/4/).

Comment: Mr Listner, it works now but why the menu displays at the top of the logo. I want the menu as well as the login link to be displayed vertically center compared to logo.

Comment: That is an entirely different question! I'm afraid you'll have to restructure your entire menu then. Currently, the ul and the img are in different divs, so they have no effect on one another.

Comment: So what is the best practice, is it good to place them in one div or separate?

Comment: The simplest way is when you know what the height of the logo is in pixels, and the height of the font in pixels, then you can set the margins of the list elements. In my [new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QupAV/25/) I assume 80px for the logo and 16px for the font, so the margin will be (80-16)/2 or 32px.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `width` of menu container in css:

```
/* line 23, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/menu.css.scss */
.header-container .header ul {
  float: left;
  width:80%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QupAV/10/)

Answer (score 0):

what about deleting  `float: left;` and  `overflow: auto;`

```
.header-container .header ul {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QupAV/6/

Comment: then the height of ul becomes zero

Comment: i guess you can set min-height.

Answer (score 0):

just set the `margin-right:5px;` instead of `2%`
**here is** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QupAV/19/).

Answer (score 0):

Made some updates to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/QupAV/22/

Here is the structure:

```
<div class='header-container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <div class='logo'>
      <img src='assets/logo.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='menu'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Features</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Team</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Support</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <a href='#'>Login</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container'></div>
<div class='footer'></div>?
```

Here are the css:

```
    .clear { clear: both; float: none; font-size: 0px; }

/* line 1, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/menu.css.scss */
.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 15%;
  background: url(menubg.jpg) no-repeat;
}
/* line 10, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/menu.css.scss */
.header-container .header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* line 16, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/menu.css.scss */
.header-container .header .logo {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left;
}
/* line 23, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/menu.css.scss */
.header-container .header .menu {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 82%;
}

.header-container .header .menu ul {
   list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
/* line 27, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/menu.css.scss */
.header-container .header ul li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
/* line 35, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/menu.css.scss */
.header-container .header a {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}?
```